# Count value of records which belong to other model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably pretty basic, but I'm trying to figure out how to show how many comments a post has in rails, on the post index page of my app.

comments belongs_to post, and post has_many comments

Just not sure how to show on the index page, the amount of comments for each post.

Thanks in advance!

Elliot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
<%= post.comments.size %>
```

You might also be interested in the [pluralize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001746) method.

```
<%= pluralize(post.comments.size, 'comment') %>
```

This will output "3 comments" or "1 comment", etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!

Comment: post.comments.size will take longer to query than post.comments.count(:all), see below.

Comment: @klochner, it is the same. "count" and "size" will both use a count(*) query for a has_many association.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong here, but you should use

`<%= post.comments.count %>` rather than `size`.

ActiveRecord knows that 'count' is a special method, and will turn it into a `SELECT count(id) from comments where post_id = x` (which is what you want).

`size` however, is not a special method, and ActiveRecord will load all the comments into an array in memory (`SELECT * from comments where post_id = x`, and then tell you how long this array is, which may be unneccessary - if you're going to loop through the array of comments further down the page, then you may want to use `size` to load them into memory, because it will need to happen later anyway.

Comment: size will also use COUNT (at least it did when i just tested it)

Comment: I just tested it and size used select *, while count used select count(*).    It may depend on the relation - mine was habtm.

Comment: I prefer to always use "size" on a has_many association. I know back in Rails 2.1 the "count" method would not take advantage of a counter cache if it was present. This may have changed in 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use some of ActiveRecord's built in functionality here. The counter_cache. Check it out [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)